# Passing arguments to a perl package while using it

Tags: perl, arguments, package

How to pass some arguments while using a package, for example:

```
use Test::More tests => 21;
```

I wasn't able to find any valuable documentation about this featue. Are there any pros and cons of passing such arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`use My::Module LIST`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#use-Module-LIST) does two things: 1) It [`require`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#require-EXPR)s `My::Module`; and 2) Invokes [`My::Module->import(LIST)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#import-LIST).

Therefore, you can write your module's `import` routine to treat the list of arguments passed any which way you want. This becomes even easier if you are indeed writing an object oriented module that does not export anything to the caller's namespace.

Here's a rather pointless example:

```
package Ex;

use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my $hello = 'Hello';
    sub import {
        my $self = shift;
        my $lang = shift || 'English';
        if ($lang eq 'Turkish') {
            $hello = 'Merhaba';
        }
        else {
            $hello = 'Hello';
        }
        return;
    }

    sub say_hello {
        my $self = shift;
        my $name = shift;

        print "$hello $name!\n";
        return;
    }
}

__PACKAGE__;
__END__
```

And a script to use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Ex 'Turkish';
Ex->say_hello('Perl');

Ex->import;
Ex->say_hello('Perl');
```

Output:

```
$ ./imp.pl
Merhaba Perl!
Hello Perl!
```

Comment: It would be nice to know how to combine the usual import (using names and tags) with the processing of special parameters (like one to skip the built-in `UNITCHECK`s). Filter out the special ones, and then call the standard importer?

Answer (score 3):

Some may say it is more readable in some scenarios, but in essence it is same as

```
use Test::More qw(tests 21);
```

(`test` is auto-quoted by fat comma `=>`, and number doesn't need quote).

Answer (score 0):

The major disadvantage is that you can't use the default `import` subroutine from [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter), which expects only a list of symbols (or tags denoting collections of symbols) to import into the calling package

[`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) inherits a custom `import` routine from the superclass [`Test::Builder::Module`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Builder::Module), which uses the arguments supplied in the `use` statement to configure the test plan. It also in turn uses `Exporter` to handle options specified like `import => [qw/ symbols to import /]`

Pretty much anything can be done by a custom `import` subroutine if you have a specific requirement, but it is probably unwise to stray too far from standard object-oriented semantics

Comment: Your custom import can fall back to using Exporter's

Comment: What of it? The first paragraph is still highly misleading if not wrong, and after a careful rereading of your answer, nothing in it refutes that.

Comment: Your = Borodin's. It = your answer. That = The first paragraph