# Why add LIST after a use statement?

Tags: perl

What's the difference between say `use File::Spec;` and `use File::Spec qw(rel2abs);`?

Believe it or not, I did try googling this first, but I guess the words *use* and *list* are too vague for Google to find anything useful.

Just to be clear, my question is *not* about the use of `qw()`. I'm just asking about the list it contains.

Comment: probably a better explanation than what I can make : https://perlmaven.com/use-require-import

Comment: Did you not find the actual documentation? https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments to a perl package while using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666896/passing-arguments-to-a-perl-package-while-using-it)

Comment: Ah. Now I see. My understanding was that it is "so that the author of that code can call add without providing the fully qualified name," as it says in that link you shared @ewong. What I failed to get the first time was that this is only the behaviour "in most cases" because "What the import method does is up to the author of the... module".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Module;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN { 
   require Module;
   Module->import();
}
```

What `import` does is up to the module. It might do nothing, it might export symbols, or it might do something else. Many modules have a default list of symbols this exports.

---

```
use Module LIST;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN { 
   require Module;
   Module->import(LIST);
}
```

What `import` does is up to the module. It might do nothing, it might export symbols, or it might do something else. Many modules will export the specified symbols (and no others).

---

```
use Module ( );
```

and

```
use Module qw( );
```

are equivalent to

```
BEGIN { 
   require Module;
}
```

`import` is not called.

---

File::Spec doesn't define or inherit an `import` method, so `use File::Spec;` and `use File::Spec qw( rel2abs );` are equivalent to `use File::Spec qw( );`. (Invoking a non-existent `import` method doesn't result in an error.) `use File::Spec qw( rel2abs );` was probably supposed to be `use File::Spec::Functions qw( rel2abs );`.

---

I almost never `use Module;`; I prefer to specify the symbols I want to import. This has two benefits:

- I don't import symbols I don't need. Avoiding namespace pollution provides a few minor benefits that amount to "less chance of being surprised".
- The people reading my code (incl myself) can easily find the module that provides an imported symbol.

Comment: This is an excellent and very comprehensive explanation. I'd maybe add the _namespace pollution_ argument to your first point in the list at the end.

Comment: @simbabque, The first reason I list *is* avoiding namespace pollution. But ok, I've added those words.